# Patent application US20120203725 conflicting with a older publication

Tags: patentability, user-interface, computer, us20120203725

This patent application claims that the collaborative merging of brain signals is a new invention. However, in an article by Yijun Wang and Tzyy-Ping Jung entitled "[A Collaborative Brain-Computer Interface for Improving Human Performance](http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3adoi/10.1371/journal.pone.0020422)" in PLOS ONE, the authors did precisely this a year before (or possibly more, given that the article was submitted in February 2011) than this patent application.
Is the patent office aware of this?

Answer (score 1):

The priority date of the application is January 19th 2011. This is about four months *before* the article's publication date. Therefore the publication itself is **not prior art** to the patent application. Also, it is not clear that the claims of the patent application are things that are "taught" by the article. Some claims cover one of two sources being human while the second is living but non-human and the case where the second is from a machine. Also the claims are not resticted to direct brain connections.

Comment: The abstract of this work was [published](http://www.abstractsonline.com/Plan/ViewAbstract.aspx?sKey=97b65b15-82a9-4008-ac9f-d4d150005a8f&cKey=a6673e96-ff9e-40f2-9077-d2407c368628&mKey=%7bE5D5C83F-CE2D-4D71-9DD6-FC7231E090FB%7d) on November 2010, so definitely before the priority date of the application...

Comment: That abstract would be prior art to the application and should be sent in to the USPTO by the applicants on an IDS if the applicants as aware of it.